# I wish to ask how to search for service names of Google API

Tags: python

I try to use

```
service = build(service_name, "v1", http=http)
```

to access Google Groups Provisioning APi. However, I tried difference names: provisioning, groupsprovisioning, etc but unsuccessful. Does anyone know the name of Groups Provisioning service? How can I search for the list of the service names available in Google Apps API.

Answer (score 0):

The Google Apps API is not available via the new API client. You need to use the old GData client, as documented on the [Apps Provisioning API page](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/provisioning/).

To answer your second question, you can use the [APIs Discovery Service](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/discovery/v1/discovery.apis.list) to list the names of all the new-style APIs.